# Реализация виджетов windows на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте! Есть ли библиотека для реализации таких виджетов на рабочем столе из Python'а?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Можно использовать PyQt5*
*Создаём скрипт и добавляем его в автозагрузку*